# Find boundaries of a shape

Tags: geometry, vectors

I have a bunch of points separated one from each other, that form a random shape (as shown on the picture)

For each of the points there is known x,y coordinates on the vector.

What I'm trying to do is to figure out how to get only those points which are located on the edge of the shape, so effectively if i join them with a line i will get a traced shape (as shown on the picture[blue line])

[image]

Will be happy to hear any advice or suggestion on how this can be achieved

Thanks

Comment: On the top half, why do you go back in steps? Would it be wrong to just connect the "ends" of the various (curved) lines?

Comment: I suspect that the ideal solution might be formulated as something like "find the connect-the-dots closed curve whose interior (unsigned) area is minimal and which contains all the dots." That can;t be QUITE right, though, for we could just order the dots and then take $P_0, \ldots, P_n, P_{n-1}, \ldots, P_0$, which would have zero area. :( I don't see, offhand, how to improve the formulation though.

Comment: Question for OP: would a set of 100 points forming the outline of a circle be a possible input? Or would the input of that shape always contain lots of points filling in the "interior" of the circle as well?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen von Eitzen the top and bottom are no doubt boundaries. Problem is in the middle points, e.g. 2nd row there is only 5 points participate in the boundary part, while the rest is within the shape. And if i connect only the ends then the shape is not exactly traced on those 5 points.

Comment: Without some condition like convexity (which your example does not satisfy), there is no real good definition of 'boundary' for a set of points. There is the notion of the convex hull of a set in the plane (the intersection of the set of all half planes which contain the set).

Comment: @jekcom Then why not trace "further in" and then back off to the net level? Maybe a condition should be: If $A,B,C$ are three points and $\angle ABC\le 90^\circ$, then $AC$ shall not be used as edge? - Actually, this could produce your suggested line e.g. by starting from the convex hull and removing such "problem" edges one by one ... (but I'm not sure if that would always be unique)

Comment: @JohnHughes no, unfortunately input of a circle is not an option because those "curves" are not part of a circle they rather sinusoidal lines